# How to compile and jar an Android project using Ant?

Tags: android, ant, build, jar

I'm trying to get a handle on this whole "Ant" buildsystem thing. I've created a build.xml that Android natively gives me by using the command: `android update project -p .` .

While this has given me a template build.xml file, I would like a couple more options. Specifically, I would like to be able to **JAR** and/or **Compile** my project; preferably with a version number.

Bonus Question: How can I exclude files from my JAR build. For example, I have one activity that I've used to test my functionality, but I don't want that to be included in the final JAR.

My build.xml file that Android has given me is Gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/1888378) since it's pretty long (mostly comments).

**EDIT**: I'm also using IntelliJ so no Eclipse specifics, please!

Comment: What do you mean by "JAR and Compile my project", considering that Android applications are not JAR files?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I really mean two "targets".
1. Compile my code so that the classes and dex files and whatever are in their correct directories. 
2. JAR those class files that I want so that I can distribute my Android "library" appropriately.

Comment: Furthermore, I should clarify. I don't know whether my project qualifies as a "library" project or not. But I just have code that uses the Android SDK that I want JARed so that I can use it in another application. Not activities, just other code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Specifically, I would like to be able to JAR and/or Compile my project; preferably with a version number.

In Android, version numbers are for apps, not JARs.

That being said, adding a `jar` target is a matter of adding this to your `build.xml` file towards the bottom:

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/whatever-you-want-to-call-the.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes"
    />
</target>
```

Then, run `ant jar` to compile and package the JAR file.

You will see this pattern in most of the reusable Android components in [my GitHub area](https://github.com/commonsguy) (see the `cwac-` repos).

> Bonus Question: How can I exclude files from my JAR build. For example, I have one activity that I've used to test my functionality, but I don't want that to be included in the final JAR.

Use `excludes` or `excludesfile`, as described in the [`jar` Ant task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Comment: Perfect. As an aside, `excludes="**/ExcludedFile.class"` excludes the file you don't like. And the `depends="debug"` is the magic that requires a pre-compilation.

Comment: @hwrdprkns Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "the magic that requires pre-compilation"? Are you saying that specifying "depends='debug'" forces ant to compile before building the jar? EDIT: Actually after reading more, does this mean that when you call "ant jar" it realizes it needs to do "ant debug" first? And I assume we use debug instead of release because we don't care about signing for a jar?

Answer (score 1):

For reuse of Android and non-android projects I would suggest you take a look at the Android Maven Plugin. It takes advantage of dependency management and other powerful features of Maven and will be much more suitable to what you want to do.

Checkout the [webpage and documentation](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) on it and maybe the chapter about [Android development in Maven : The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html) I wrote to get a bit more understanding as well as have something to look at about Maven.

The Android plugin supports reuse for normal jar artifacts and if there are Android dependencies within the code you can use apklib projects. Lots of projects like Roboguice, robolectric, actionbarsherlock and others use this feature successfully.

Comment: Not what the question asked for, but +1 since this looks like an an awesome tool that I should get to know.

Comment: No problem.. just trying to save you from xml hell and lots of upgrade pains once you start customizing the ant build..